# Match pattern in text

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1> <h2>What is {{ $slot }} Ipsum?</h2> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to {{$example }}make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially {{$category1 }} unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more {{ $Product2}} recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I tried to match the following patterns:

```
{{ $slot }}
{{$example }}
{{ $Product2}}
{{$category1 }}
```

My current regex looks like the following, `^{{\s*$\w\s*}}`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Remove `^` that means `Start of the string`, use `\b` that means `word boundary` ( [see](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) )to match exactly a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex does not match your values because you are asserting the start of the line `^`, you have to escape the dollar sign `\$` to match it literally and you have to use a quantifier like for example `+`  to match a word character one or more times `\w+`

You could use:

`{{\s*\$\w+\s*}}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MfDjGT/1)

Explanation:

- `{{` Match literally
- `\s*` Match a whitespace character zero or more times
- `\$` Match a dollar sign
- `\s*` Match a whitespace character zero or more times
- `}}` Match literally

Answer (score 2):

Use expression:

```
{{[^}]*}}
```

- `{{` Two opening brackets.
- `[^}]*` Negated character set, anything other than a `}`.
- `}}` Two closing brackets.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qZiBbl/1).